# app crashes on assert()

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ftp

I am sending an audio file with extension .m4a on the server using ftp protocol for that firstly I store this file into my document directory path. I got document directory path in my console as follows:

```
NSLog(@"filepath=%@",filePath);
assert([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]);
```

at the assert() function my app crases I don't know what is the reason.
My console is as follows:

```
filepath=/Users/macmini2/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/B2CFB7FF-A4BF-4B83-8DD1-102C5680C16C/Documents/9_39.m4a
Assertion failed: ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])
```

if you have any solution plz provide
thanx in advance...

Comment: The reason is that file you are looking for does not exists at path. I don't know do you know how asserts work. I'll explain a little. If an assert fails (in debug mode) your code will break on that line for you to be able to make observation about current situation. You can basically remove that line. Your code will work the same.

Comment: but i print the message in console it shows me the path of the file.

Comment: Just because you can print a path to a file it doesn't mean that any file necessarily exists at that path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is highly likely that the file you are looking for is not there.

For a double check, enter:

```
ls "/Users/macmini2/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.1/Applications/B2CFB7FF-A4BF-4B83-8DD1-102C5680C16C/Documents/9_39.m4a"
```

in a terminal window.

In case you get an error, please, review the way you build `filePath`.

How do you make the 9_39.m4a file available on your iPhone? Is it part of the app bundle? (Should you not then search for it in the Resources folder?)